# Eclipse Content Assist for composite components in JSF 2 don´t show

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

I,m developing a composite component to generate a selectOneMenu from a DB data list according to name pass by parameter.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:jsf="http://java.sun.com/jsf"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">    
    <cc:interface componentType="pseudocatalog" >   
        <cc:attribute name="paramsName" default="" displayName="paramsName" expert="false" hidden="false" preferred="true" shortDescription="Descripcion de prueba"/>
        <cc:attribute name="paramsValue" default="" displayName="paramsValue"  shortDescription="Descripcion de prueba"/>
        <cc:attribute name="paramsType" type="java.lang.String" default="" displayName="paramsType" shortDescription="Descripcion de prueba"/>
        <cc:attribute name="storedProcedure" type="java.lang.String" default="" displayName="storedProcedure" shortDescription="Descripcion de prueba"/>
        <cc:attribute name="nextAutomatic" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="true" displayName="nextAutomatic"/>    
        <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.String" default="" displayName="value"/>
        <cc:attribute name="mode" type="java.lang.String" default="" shortDescription="" displayName="mode"/>
        <cc:attribute name="autocomplete" type="java.lang.String" default="" displayName="autocomplete"/>
        <cc:attribute name="loadDefaultOption" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="true" displayName="loadDefaultOption"/>
        <cc:attribute name="order" type="java.lang.String" default="asc" displayName="order"/>      
        <cc:clientBehavior name="change" targets="#{cc.id}" event="change" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="#{cc.id}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" >                      
            <f:selectItems value="#{cc.items}"/>            
        </h:selectOneMenu>      
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

And the new component renders fine but eclipse don´t show the content assistant for the attributes.

[image]

For another library components like *rich* or *h* the content assistant works fine

What´s wrong?

Comment: You miss the eclipse version being used ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the tardiness, my components library is exported as jar archive, my eclipse versión is Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1). I've read your links and despite the components work, eclipse not show help.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, at least, I couldn't achieve it. Eclipse is able to identify the tag name for the composite itself, but not its attributes. You can see it also in the [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fwhats_new.htm). What you could do is to [declare it](https://blog.oio.de/2012/05/23/custom-tags-as-an-alternative-to-composite-components-in-jsf/) as a tag library, so eclipse could recognize them parsing the declaration file.

Comment: Sorry for the tardiness, my components library is exported as jar archive, my eclipse versión is Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1). I've read your links and despite the components work, eclipse not show help